# JMeter - Can't use Java stream in JSR223 script

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter, java-stream, jsr223

I can't use Java stream inside JSR223 script in JMeter,

I tried with [Java stream](https://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/)

```
List<String> myList =
    Arrays.asList("a1", "a2", "b1", "c2", "c1");

myList
    .stream()
    .filter(s -> s.startsWith("c"))
    .map(String::toUpperCase)
    .sorted()
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

With exception

```
2019-04-22 13:44:49,808 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script9.groovy: 6: unexpected token: -> @ line 6, column 15.
       .filter(s -> s.startsWith("c"))
                 ^

1 error

javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script9.groovy: 6: unexpected token: -> @ line 6, column 15.
       .filter(s -> s.startsWith("c"))
                 ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.compile(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:187) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:217) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:71) [ApacheJMeter_java.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
```

I tried with [groovy stream](https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2018/06/groovy-goodness-java-8-stream.html)

> ```
> def sample = ['Groovy', 'Gradle', 'Grails', 'Spock'] as String[]
>
> def result = sample.stream()  // Use stream() on array objects
>                .filter { s -> s.startsWith('Gr') }
>                .map { s -> s.toUpperCase() }
>                .toList()  // toList() added to Stream by Groovy
> ```

With exception:

```
019-04-22 13:42:40,345 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [Ljava.lang.String;.stream() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: grep(), size(), sort(), sum(), grep(), head()
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [Ljava.lang.String;.stream() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: grep(), size(), sort(), sum(), grep(), head()
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:324) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
```

And [beanshell isn't supporting streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849019/how-to-use-or-escape-java-8-lambda-expressions-in-beanshell)

> Lambda expressions still not supported in beanshell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groovy does not support `lambda` however you can replace lambda with `Closure` like below:

```
​List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("a1", "a2", "b1", "c2", "c1");  
myList.stream()
       .filter{s -> s.startsWith("c")}
       .map{s-> s.toUpperCase()}
       .sorted()
       .forEach{s->println s};​
```

Output:

```
C1
C2
```

Your second case gives you the error as the sample is an Array and `stream()` is not available on Array. You can get stream by `Arrays.stream(array)`.

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

def sample = ['Groovy', 'Gradle', 'Grails', 'Spock'] as String[]  
def result = Arrays.stream(sample )
                        .filter { s -> s.startsWith('Gr') }                
                        .map { s -> s.toUpperCase() }                
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())​
```

Comment: Getting different exception on inside the `forEach`: `javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script11.groovy: 6: Invalid variable name. Must start with a letter but was: ​
. At [6:31]  @ line 6, column 31.
          .forEach{s->println s};`

Comment: @user7294900 Can you please double check your syntax. It is working fine in my case. Please visit the link https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5173177101582336

Comment: I'm executing inside JMeter, using JSR223 Sampler, is that are you executing?

Comment: For your 2nd case https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5151353835880448

Comment: No, I am executing on groovy console but it should work on Jmeter

Comment: How to print all stream results?

Comment: @user7294900 from your error (commented) it looks like there is some other issue which is not related to Stream. Maybe bad variable name declaration.

Comment: There are several ways to print. You can Use `forEach{s->println s};​` to print the result or just loop over the result collection and simple print it.

Comment: `forEach{s->println s}` doesn't works, or syntax as `OUT::println`

Comment: @user7294900 Use `forEach{s->OUT.println(s)}` in case of Jmeter.